chainlitにpdfファイルを渡したい
chainlitでpdfファイルを読み込み、その書類についてLLMが回答してくれるチャットbotを作りたいと思っています。下記のサイトを参考にしています。
https://www.salesanalytics.co.jp/datascience/datascience173/#PDFapp_pdfpy
コードはサイトそのままでディレクトリ構造は以下の通りです。
chatbot----pycache
|--app_pdf.py
|_doc
|_doc.pdf
chainlitを起動し、ファイルをドロップするところまでは問題ないですが、ファイルの読
み込みで
AttributeError: 'AskFileResponse' object has no attribute 'content'

というエラーが出てしまいます。
app_pdf.pyは以下の通りです
# 必要なモジュールの読み込み
import os
import shutil
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import chainlit as cl
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
# 定数設定
OPENAI_API_KEY = "<OpenAI APIキー>"
TEMP_PDF_PATH = "./doc/doc.pdf"
CHUNK_SIZE = 500
CHUNK_OVERLAP = 10
DB_PATH = './.chroma'
MODEL_NAME = "gpt-4"
# OpenAI APIキーの設定
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = OPENAI_API_KEY
# PDFファイルを開いてテキストを抽出する関数
async def process_pdf(file):
    file = file[0] if isinstance(file, list) else file
    with open(TEMP_PDF_PATH, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file.content)
    reader = PdfReader(TEMP_PDF_PATH)
    return ''.join(page.extract_text() for page in reader.pages)
# テキストを分割し、埋め込みを作成してデータベースを作成する関数
async def create_db(text):
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE, chunk_overlap=CHUNK_OVERLAP)
    docs = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    metadatas = [{"source": f"{i}-pl"} for i in range(len(docs))]
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    db = Chroma.from_texts(docs, embeddings, metadatas=metadatas)
    return db, docs
# チャットボットの初期化処理
@cl.on_chat_start
async def init():
    file = None
    while file is None:
        file = await cl.AskFileMessage(content="PDFファイルをアップロードしてください！", accept=["pdf"]).send()
    # データベースの初期化
    shutil.rmtree(DB_PATH, ignore_errors=True)
    # ファイルからテキストを抽出し、データベースを作成
    text = await process_pdf(file)
    db, docs = await create_db(text)
    chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
        ChatOpenAI(model=MODEL_NAME,temperature=0),
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=db.as_retriever(),
    )
    # テキストをユーザーセッションに保存
    cl.user_session.set("texts", docs)
    file_name = file[0].name if isinstance(file, list) else file.name
    await cl.Message(content=f"`{file_name}` の準備が完了しました！").send()
    return chain
# 応答を処理する関数
@cl.on_message
def process_response(res):
    texts = cl.user_session.get("texts")
    sources = res["sources"].strip().split(',')
    source_elements = [cl.Text(content=texts[int(s[:s.find('-pl')])], name=s) for s in sources if s]
    response = f"{res['answer']} 出典: {res['sources']}"
    cl.Message(content=response, elements=source_elements).send()

どなたかわかる方がいたら教えていただきたいです。

OpenAI の API キーが質問文に含まれてしまっていたため、編集履歴も含め完全に削除する修正をモデレーターが行いました。API キーなどの認証情報は、外部に公開された場合第三者があなたのアカウント情報を使って操作できてしまう可能性があるものです。今後お気をつけください。
